# Closing AutoCompleteBox loses Focus to Browser

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0, autocomplete, focus

I've extended an the AutoCompleteBox of Silverlight and overridden the OnDropDownClosed event handler. This works as expected except that the component looses the focus to the Browser once the DropDown is closed.

What do I have to change in order to keep it?

Here's my code:

```
namespace ITPole.Sphere.Application.Core.Controls
{

    using System.Windows;
    using System.Windows.Controls;
    using System.Windows.Media;

    public class CustomCompleteBox : AutoCompleteBox
    {    
        public static readonly DependencyProperty SelectedAtCloseProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register(
                "SelectedAtClose", typeof(object), typeof(CustomCompleteBox), new PropertyMetadata(null));

        public object SelectedAtClose
        {
            get
            {
                return this.GetValue(SelectedAtCloseProperty);
            }

            set
            {
                this.SetValue(SelectedAtCloseProperty, value);
            }
        }

        protected override void OnDropDownClosed(RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<bool> e)
        {
            base.OnDropDownClosed(e);
            this.SelectedAtClose = this.SelectedItem;

        }

        protected override void OnTextChanged(RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnTextChanged(e);

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.Text))
            {
                this.SetValue(SelectedAtCloseProperty, null);
            }
        }

    }
}
```

And the usage in xaml:

```
<Controls1:CustomCompleteBox x:Name="portfolioAutoCompleteBox"
                             Grid.Column="1"
                             Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                             Grid.Row="1"
                             Margin="2"
                             DataContext="{Binding Portfolio}"
                             Style="{StaticResource DefaultAutoCompleteBoxStyle}"
                             ItemTemplate="{StaticResource DescriptionItemTemplate}"
                             ValueMemberBinding="{Binding Description, Mode=TwoWay}"
                             SelectedAtClose="{Binding Value, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True, Mode=TwoWay}"
                             ItemsSource="{Binding Values}"
                             Text="{Binding Text, Mode=TwoWay}"
                             Behaviors:AutoCompleteBoxBehaviors.PopulatingCommand="{Binding PopulationCommand}" />
```

Answer (score 0):

What version of Silverlight are you using? It works for me with V4.

Comment: Does that mean it's a xaml-problem?